# Error 400. The request has an invalid header name ESP8266 (HTTP-POST)

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, web-server, networking, http

I'm trying to send a http post to my server from an esp8266-Wifi (I use the ESP8266 library)

I check all my http post format, and I guess is okay... but at the response, the monitor serial **answer** me like this:

```
Requesting POST: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Sat, 10 Jun 2017 23:12:48 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 339

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

closing connection
```

and this is my code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
const char* ssid     = "Putostodosmenosyo";
const char* password = "CetriX.2016%Gdl";

const char* host = "187.201.44.110";

const String Cadenadatos = "info=Micanton|2017-06-09%2012:00|25" ;
//const String Tamano = String(Cadenadatos.length()) ;
const String postiu = "POST /wsCo2Keellingv1002/wsCo2Keelling.asmx/GuardaInfoArduino HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:187.201.44.110:80\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length:144\r\n\r\n?info="+String(Cadenadatos)+"\n" ;
const String postam = String(postiu);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(100);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); 
  delay(2000) ;
}

void loop() {

  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  if (!client.connect(host,httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("Conexion fallida");
    return;
  }


 //String data = "pst=temperature>" + String(random(0,100)) +"||humidity>" + String(random(0,100)) + "||data>text";

   Serial.print("Requesting POST: ");
   // Send request to the server:
   //client.println("POST /wsCo2Keellingv1002/wsCo2Keelling.asmx/GuardaInfoArduino HTTP/1.1");
   //client.println();
   //client.println("co2kelling.hopto.org") ;
   client.println("POST /wsCo2Keellingv1002/wsCo2Keelling.asmx/GuardaInfoArduino HTTP/1.1");
   client.println("Host: co2kelling.hopto.org");
   client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   client.print("Content-length: ");
   client.print(postiu.length());
   client.println();
   client.print(String(Cadenadatos));
   while(client.connected())
   {
    while(client.available())
    //String line = client.readStringUntil('\r') ;
    Serial.write(client.read()) ;
   }

   /*delay(500); // Can be changed
  if (client.connected()) { 
    client.stop();  // DISCONNECT FROM THE SERVER
  }*/
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
  delay(5000);
}
```

**NOTE**: this is my fixed url
*http://187.201.44.110/wsCo2Keellingv1002/wsCo2Keelling.asmx/GuardaInfoArduino?info=Micanton|2017-06-09%2012:00|25*

**EDIT**

This is my Post format:

```
POST /wsCo2Keellingv1002/wsCo2Keelling.asmx/GuardaInfoArduino HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length
info=string
```

Answer (score 1):

You are lacking the required blank line between the headers and the content. Also your content length is wrong.

Change

```
client.print(postiu.length());
```

Into

```
client.println(Cadenadatos.length());
```

Comment: "closing connection
Requesting POST:"

This is now the response.

Comment: I just spotted your content length uses the wrong value. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I solved my problem, thanks Majenko.